# How can I get raw packet from client?

Tags: c#, sockets

I want to get raw packet data from client and I read this post:
[C# Getting packet data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850948/c-sharp-getting-packet-data)
but I can't understand this line:

```
s.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(strIP), 80));
log(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));
```

1. `strIP`, is that the server ip?
2. what does the `log` call do?

Answer (score 1):

The `strIP` is the variable that holds the IP address of the endpoint.

The `log()` line is to log a string version of what is received - probably to a log file somewhere that is defined earlier in the code.

Comment: @elnazirani Yes. `new IPEndPoint(serverIPAddress, 80)` is the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
strIP = Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[0].ToString();
```

To get your local ip address.

And the `log()` should be look like this.

```
private void log(string log)
{
    Console.WritelLine(log); //or append this text in any text file 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use the pcapDotNet library in c#.
https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/